# Login and Registration using PHP & MySQL displays html tags in response

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, authentication

I have made an Login and registration activities.
I am not able to login as well as register in the database. I send the data from the activities to login.php and Registration.php respectively. I am using wamp server.

The problem is in BackroundTask.java where the response is returned from server as Html tags. How do I eliminate them from the echo message of login.php & registration.php

BackgroundTask.java

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

// AlertDialog alertDialog;

Context ctx;
BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx=ctx;

}


@Override
public String doInBackground(String... params) {


        String reg_url="http://10.0.2.2/webapp/Register.php";
        String login_url="http://10.0.2.2/webapp/login.php";
             String method= params[0];
        if(method.equals("register"))
        {
            String name=params[1];
            String u_address=params[2];
            String user_pass=params[3];
            String u_email=params[4];
            String u_zip=params[5];
            String u_mob=params[6];

            try {
                URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("address","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(u_address,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_pass,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("emailid","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(u_email,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("zip","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(u_zip,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("mob","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(u_mob,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                os.close();
               BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));

                String result;
                result = bufferedReader.readLine();
               // / InputStream is= httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
               // is.close();
               // return "Registration Success...";
                return result;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
            /*catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/
        }

    else {
            if (method.equals("login")) {
                String login_name = params[1];
                String login_pass = params[2];
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(login_url);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
                    String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                            URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");

                    bufferedWriter.write(data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    os.close();

                    InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                    String response="";
                    String line="";
                    while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        response+=line;
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    return response;

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                /*catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/
            }
        }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
   // alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
   // alertDialog.setTitle("Login information...");
    super.onPreExecute();
/*    if(response.equals("Login Success...")){
        Toast.makeText(ctx,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(response.equals("Login Failed!Try again")) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx,"Login failed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //alertDialog.setMessage(log);
        //alertDialog.show();
    }
   */
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   /* if(result.equals("Registration Success...")){
        Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
    //if(result.equals("Login Success...")){
        //  Toast.makeText(ctx,"Login Success!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    /*else
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx,"Failed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } */

   /* if(method.equals("login"))
    { */
        if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("Login Success..."))
        {

            Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,MainActivity.class);
          //  intent.putExtra("USER_NAME",login_name);
            ctx.startActivity(intent);

        }


   /*     else{
            Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else if(method.equals("register")) {
   */
        else if (result.equals("Registered Successfully")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,Login.class);
            ctx.startActivity(intent);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
   // }
}

}
```

In the Login activity when I try to login with correct values I see a toast message with html tags like this

[image: Login page]

Login page is displayed as shown above.

After filling values in registration page I see only a `<br>` tag in Toast as shown below

[image: Registration confirmation]

For reference I have attached my code

init.php

```
<?php
db_name="citizen";
$mysql_user="root";
$mysql_pass="";
$server_name="localhost";

$con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);

if(!$con)
{
echo"Connection Error...";
}
else
{
echo"Database connection Success...";
}

?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
require"init.php";

$user_name=$_POST["login_name"];
$user_pass=$_POST["login_pass"];

//$sql_query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM reg WHERE 'Email' = '$user_name' AND 'Password'='$user_pass'");
$sql_query="SELECT Name FROM reg WHERE Email like '$user_name' AND Password like   '$user_pass';";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);
//$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
//$data=$row[0];
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
//if($data)
{
echo"Login Success...";
} 
else
{
echo"Login Failed!Try again";
}
//mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Registration.php

```
    <?php
require 'init.php';
$name=$_POST["user"];
$address=$_POST["address"];
$user_pass=$_POST["user_pass"];
$emailid=$_POST["emailid"];
$zip=$_POST["zip"];
$mob=$_POST["mob"];
$sql_query="INSERT INTO reg VALUES('$name','$address','$user_pass','$emailid','$zip','$mob');";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query))
{
echo"Registered Successfully";
}
else
{
echo"Registration Failed";
}

?>
```

The code is as follows

Login.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText ET_NAME,ET_PASS;
String login_name,login_pass;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
 ET_NAME=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_name);
 ET_PASS=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_pass);

}


public void userLogin(View view)
{
    login_name=ET_NAME.getText().toString();
    login_pass=ET_PASS.getText().toString();
    String method="login";
    if (!isValidEmail(login_name)) {
        ET_NAME.setError("Invalid Email");
    }

    if (!isValidPassword(login_pass)) {
        ET_PASS.setError("Invalid Password");
    }
    else {
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(method, login_name, login_pass);
    }
    //Intent getIssues= new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    //getIssues.putExtra("MA", );
    //this.startActivity(getIssues);
}
private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}

// validating password with retype password
private boolean isValidPassword(String pass) {
    if (pass != null && pass.length() > 6) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public void userReg(View view)
{
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Registration.class));
}
}
```

Registration.java

```
public class Registration extends Activity
{

EditText ETname, ETrpassword, ETpassword, ETaddress, ETemail, ETzip, ETmob;
String name, address, userpass, email, ruserpass, zip, mob;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);


    ETname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ETaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    ETemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    ETpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordfield);
    ETrpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    ETzip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ETmob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    Button reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regbutton);

}

public void reg(View view) {
    name = ETname.getText().toString();
    address = ETaddress.getText().toString();
    userpass = ETpassword.getText().toString();
    ruserpass = ETrpassword.getText().toString();
    email = ETemail.getText().toString();
    zip = ETzip.getText().toString();
    mob = ETmob.getText().toString();

    String method = "register";

     boolean cancel = true;


    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name) || name.length() < 3) {
        ETname.setError(getString(R.string.error_validname_required));
        cancel = false;
    }


    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(address) || address.length()<15) {
        ETaddress.setError("Invalid address");
        cancel = false;
    }

    if(ruserpass.isEmpty())
    {
        ETrpassword.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        cancel=false;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userpass) || userpass.length()<6) {
        ETpassword.setError("Fill atleast 6 characters");
        cancel = false;
    }
    if(!userpass.equals(ruserpass))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password mismatch",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        cancel=false;
    }

    if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
        ETemail.setError("Invalid Email");
        cancel = false;
    }
    if(zip.length()!=6)
    {
        ETzip.setError("Invalid PINCODE");
        cancel = false;
    }
    if(mob.length()!=10)
    {
        ETmob.setError("Invalid number");
        cancel = false;
    }

    /*     boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    ETname.setError(null);
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
        ETname.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = ETname;
        cancel = true;
    }

    ETpassword.setError(null);
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(address)) {
        ETaddress.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = ETaddress;
        cancel = true;
    }


    ETaddress.setError(null);
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(address)) {
        ETaddress.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = ETaddress;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (name.length() < 3) {
        ETname.setError(getString(R.string.error_validname_required));
        focusView = ETname;
        cancel = true;
    }  */
    // }


    else if(cancel==true){
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(method, name, address, userpass, email, zip, mob);
        finish();
    }
}
private boolean isValidEmail(String email)
{
    String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}
}
```

Even in alert box I see the same html tags. I'm a beginner in android and I'm still learning it. Please help me fix this issue. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: login.php: `db_name` must be `$db_name`.

Comment: Hello Chetan! Please try to narrow down your problem to a minimal, complete and verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You're basically asking us to debug your whole code.

Comment: okay i'll point out where the problem exists

Comment: you solved my problem. I'll be careful to avoid such silly mistakes.This screwed me 4 days.That was very helpful @mitkosoft

Comment: @Chetan, you are welcome. I would like to suggest you to start using more powerful IDE software for development (like NetBeans) in order to safe time - such IDE shows you which line/part of code is wrong. I've spent 10 seconds to found it with.

Comment: @mitkosoft thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a silly mistake in init.php 
The corrected code is

```
<?php
$db_name="citizen";
$mysql_user="root";
$mysql_pass="";
$server_name="localhost";

$con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);

if($con)
{
echo"Connection success...";
}
else
{
echo"Connection failed...";
}

?>
```